# Run Angular application at server side

Tags: angular, protractor

I have an Angular 8 application that generates a PDF. Now, I need to run this in a headless browser to generate the PDF at server side.

So I'm thinking on using Protractor and Node.js, but all the examples that I find are test cases that are run with Protractor/Selenium, and I don't need to run a test.

Is Protractor the right tool to run Angular in a headless browser? If yes, what would be an example without Selenium?

Comment: Angular Universal? Puppeteer?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of Puppeteer

Comment: Are you trying to create an image snapshot of your angular app in order to put it in a PDF document?

Comment: No, today the user can click on a button and generate a PDF. I want to do the same at the server side and then send the PDF via email.